# How to associate the same code when doing SUM()?

Tags: window-functions, cumulative-sum, sql-server-2019, inventory-management

I am doing a SUM() OVER(PARTITION BY ORDER BY ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)

### Using SQL Server 2019

I have 2 tables:  Sales and Inventory.

I am trying to associate inventory numbers **(DWF_INVENTORY_NUMBER_DESC)** which represent batches of item quantities in inventory (DWF_INVENTORY_QUANTITY) to items and their invoices. Each item (DWF_SALES_ITEM_CODE) that is invoiced in sales with a certain sales Qty (DWF_SALES_SALES_QTY) should represent a purchase (DWF_SALES_INVOICE_NUM) and should then be pulled from inventory (DWF_INVENTORY_QUANTITY reduced).  I have multiple invoices for the same item.  I also have multiple inventory batches with different inventory batch numbers with their own associated quantities and their items in inventory. I need to be able to use the first in-first out (FIFO) strategy when I am pulling from inventory. In other words, I need to be able to only pull from one inventory number (batch) at one time with the earliest inventory date (meaning 1st in for DWF_INVENTORY_DELIVERY_DATE).  However, in my script, it looks like I am pulling from multiple inventory numbers (batches) for the same item, which I do not want to have happen.

My current & expected results are the following (note that my shrinking running sum DWF_INVENTORY_RUNNING_BALANCE_QTY is working well):

[image]

I feel like I am super close, but I just need that final piece of advice to get my results in order. The condition should be that the oldest delivery date (that is also older than the invoice date) with the corresponding batch number should be associated to the corresponding item and its associated invoice. Once the initial inventory batch of 5000 units of QTY have reached zero, THEN we could associate the next inventory batch number (example, DWF_INVENTORY_NUMBER_DESC is 13763002028961) when newer invoice transactions come in the future.

See below scripts to recreate the entire scenario.

Build both sales and inventory tables with data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DWF_INVENTORY](
[DWF_INVENTORY_ITEM_CD] [varchar](50) NULL,
[DWF_INVENTORY_DELIVERY_DATE] [varchar](50) NULL,
[DWF_INVENTORY_NUMBER_DESC] [varchar](50) NULL,
[DWF_INVENTORY_QUANTITY] [int] NULL,
[DWF_INVENTORY_ACCUMULATED_QTY] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[DWF_SALES]    Script Date: 8/25/2021 12:13:27 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DWF_SALES](
    [DWF_SALES_INVOICE_NUM] [int] NOT NULL,
    [DWF_SALES_INVOICE_DATE] [datetime2](7) NOT NULL,
    [DWF_SALES_ITEM_CODE] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [DWF_SALES_SALES_QTY] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DWF_INVENTORY] ([DWF_INVENTORY_ITEM_CD], [DWF_INVENTORY_DELIVERY_DATE], [DWF_INVENTORY_NUMBER_DESC], [DWF_INVENTORY_QUANTITY], [DWF_INVENTORY_ACCUMULATED_QTY]) VALUES (N'TU-1055', N'2019-10-31', N'13763001924657', 5000, 5000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DWF_INVENTORY] ([DWF_INVENTORY_ITEM_CD], [DWF_INVENTORY_DELIVERY_DATE], [DWF_INVENTORY_NUMBER_DESC], [DWF_INVENTORY_QUANTITY], [DWF_INVENTORY_ACCUMULATED_QTY]) VALUES (N'TU-1055', N'2020-11-20', N'13763002028961', 5000, 10000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DWF_INVENTORY] ([DWF_INVENTORY_ITEM_CD], [DWF_INVENTORY_DELIVERY_DATE], [DWF_INVENTORY_NUMBER_DESC], [DWF_INVENTORY_QUANTITY], [DWF_INVENTORY_ACCUMULATED_QTY]) VALUES (N'TU-1055', N'2021-01-08', N'13763002038565', 5000, 15000)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DWF_SALES] ([DWF_SALES_INVOICE_NUM], [DWF_SALES_INVOICE_DATE], [DWF_SALES_ITEM_CODE], [DWF_SALES_SALES_QTY]) VALUES (395395, CAST(N'2021-05-13T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2), N'TU-1055', 4)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DWF_SALES] ([DWF_SALES_INVOICE_NUM], [DWF_SALES_INVOICE_DATE], [DWF_SALES_ITEM_CODE], [DWF_SALES_SALES_QTY]) VALUES (411239, CAST(N'2021-07-26T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2), N'TU-1055', 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DWF_SALES] ([DWF_SALES_INVOICE_NUM], [DWF_SALES_INVOICE_DATE], [DWF_SALES_ITEM_CODE], [DWF_SALES_SALES_QTY]) VALUES (378789, CAST(N'2021-02-23T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2), N'TU-1055', 100)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DWF_SALES] ([DWF_SALES_INVOICE_NUM], [DWF_SALES_INVOICE_DATE], [DWF_SALES_ITEM_CODE], [DWF_SALES_SALES_QTY]) VALUES (313564, CAST(N'2020-02-05T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2), N'TU-1055', 30)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[DWF_SALES] ([DWF_SALES_INVOICE_NUM], [DWF_SALES_INVOICE_DATE], [DWF_SALES_ITEM_CODE], [DWF_SALES_SALES_QTY]) VALUES (327469, CAST(N'2020-05-04T00:00:00.0000000' AS DateTime2), N'TU-1055', 350)
GO
```

Here is my script with the current results:

```
SELECT
DWF_SALES_INVOICE_NUM,DWF_SALES_INVOICE_DATE
,DWF_INVENTORY_NUMBER_DESC
,DWF_INVENTORY_DELIVERY_DATE
,INVENTORY_NUM_STATUS
,DWF_INVENTORY_ITEM_CD
,CASE
    WHEN DWF_INVENTORY_RUNNING_BALANCE_QTY < 0 THEN 0
    ELSE DWF_INVENTORY_RUNNING_BALANCE_QTY
END AS DWF_INVENTORY_RUNNING_BALANCE_QTY
,DWF_INVENTORY_QUANTITY
,CASE
    WHEN DWF_SALES_RUNNING_BALANCE_QTY < 0 THEN 0
    ELSE DWF_SALES_RUNNING_BALANCE_QTY
END AS DWF_SALES_RUNNING_BALANCE_QTY
,DWF_SALES_SALES_QTY
FROM (
SELECT
    DWF_SALES_INVOICE_NUM,DWF_SALES_INVOICE_DATE
    ,DWF_INVENTORY_NUMBER_DESC
    ,DWF_INVENTORY_DELIVERY_DATE
    ,INVENTORY_NUM_STATUS
    ,DWF_INVENTORY_ITEM_CD
    ,CASE
        WHEN INVENTORY_NUM_STATUS='NOT ALLOCATED' THEN 0
        ELSE (DWF_INVENTORY_QUANTITY-
                    SUM(DWF_SALES_SALES_QTY_forInvRunnBlnCalculate) OVER(PARTITION BY DWF_INVENTORY_ITEM_CD ORDER BY DWF_INVENTORY_DELIVERY_DATE,DWF_SALES_INVOICE_DATE
                                    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW))
    END AS DWF_INVENTORY_RUNNING_BALANCE_QTY
    ,DWF_INVENTORY_QUANTITY
    ,CASE
        WHEN INVENTORY_NUM_STATUS='NOT ALLOCATED' THEN (DWF_INVENTORY_QUANTITY-DWF_SALES_SALES_QTY)
        ELSE 0
    END AS DWF_SALES_RUNNING_BALANCE_QTY
    ,DWF_SALES_SALES_QTY
FROM (
    SELECT b.DWF_SALES_INVOICE_NUM,b.DWF_SALES_INVOICE_DATE
    ,a.DWF_INVENTORY_NUMBER_DESC
    ,a.DWF_INVENTORY_DELIVERY_DATE
    ,CASE
        WHEN (a.DWF_INVENTORY_DELIVERY_DATE > b.DWF_SALES_INVOICE_DATE) 
            AND (a.DWF_INVENTORY_QUANTITY - SUM(b.DWF_SALES_SALES_QTY) OVER(PARTITION BY a.DWF_INVENTORY_ITEM_CD ORDER BY a.DWF_INVENTORY_DELIVERY_DATE,b.DWF_SALES_INVOICE_DATE 
                                    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)) < 1
            THEN 'NOT ALLOCATED'
        ELSE ''
    END AS INVENTORY_NUM_STATUS
    ,CASE
        WHEN (a.DWF_INVENTORY_DELIVERY_DATE > b.DWF_SALES_INVOICE_DATE) 
            AND (a.DWF_INVENTORY_QUANTITY - SUM(b.DWF_SALES_SALES_QTY) OVER(PARTITION BY a.DWF_INVENTORY_ITEM_CD ORDER BY a.DWF_INVENTORY_DELIVERY_DATE,b.DWF_SALES_INVOICE_DATE 
                                    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)) < 0
            THEN 0
        ELSE DWF_SALES_SALES_QTY
    END AS DWF_SALES_SALES_QTY_forInvRunnBlnCalculate
    ,a.DWF_INVENTORY_ITEM_CD
    ,a.DWF_INVENTORY_QUANTITY - SUM(b.DWF_SALES_SALES_QTY) OVER(PARTITION BY a.DWF_INVENTORY_ITEM_CD ORDER BY a.DWF_INVENTORY_DELIVERY_DATE,b.DWF_SALES_INVOICE_DATE 
                                    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS DWF_INVENTORY_RUNNING_BALANCE_QTY
    ,a.DWF_INVENTORY_QUANTITY
    ,b.DWF_SALES_SALES_QTY - SUM(a.DWF_INVENTORY_QUANTITY) OVER(PARTITION BY a.DWF_INVENTORY_ITEM_CD ORDER BY a.DWF_INVENTORY_DELIVERY_DATE,b.DWF_SALES_INVOICE_DATE 
                                    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS DWF_SALES_RUNNING_BALANCE_QTY
    ,b.DWF_SALES_SALES_QTY
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.DWF_INVENTORY_ITEM_CD ORDER BY a.DWF_INVENTORY_DELIVERY_DATE,b.DWF_SALES_INVOICE_DATE) AS rowNum
    FROM [dbo].[DWF_INVENTORY] AS a
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[DWF_SALES] AS b ON a.DWF_INVENTORY_ITEM_CD=b.DWF_SALES_ITEM_CODE
    WHERE b.DWF_SALES_SALES_QTY >= 0
) AS tblA) AS tblB;
```

I know that I need to create some kind of conditional logic for my DWF_INVENTORY_NUMBER_DESC column or perhaps create a subquery, a CTE, or a temporary table to store the MIN(DWF_INVENTORY_DELIVERY_DATE), but am not sure exactly how to proceed.

Summary of the conditions to associate the same inventory number in my resulting records, when ...

```
... the DWF_INVENTORY_NUMBER_DESC is associated to the good item (DWF_INVENTORY_ITEM_CODE = DWF_SALES_ITEM_CODE)
... the DWF_INVENTORY_DELIVERY_DATE is the oldest/earliest
... the DWF_INVENTORY_DELIVERY_DATE < DWF_SALES_INVOICE_DATE
... the DWF_INVENTORY_RUNNING_BALANCE_QTY > 0

move on to next DWF_INVENTORY_NUMBER_DESC, when ...
... DWF_INVENTORY_RUNNING_BALANCE_QTY reaches zero
```

then follow again the above conditions.

Hopefully, this makes more sense on now to be able to re-use same DWF_INVENTORY_NUMBER_DESC for the records in the resulting script?

Any help in completing my reduced running SUM script would be appreciated.

Hopefully, all of my explanations above were clear enough as it's not a super straightforward problem!

Answer (score 0):

So, I have resolved my own issue by writing to a temp table and storing the Inventory number where MIN(Delivery Date), which gets updated accordingly.